# How to mass assign objects in java

Tags: java, object, charts

Removed to avoid plagiarism...

Comment: Are you trying to create an `array`.?

Comment: I think I already have the array called bars on line two.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I don't know how that link would help him.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis They are attempting to name a `Bar` variable with the `String` in `bars[i]`, thus the _dynamic variable name_. Why they're doing this is beyond me. If they clarify their question, we can vote to reopen.

Comment: Not sure what i need to clarify? Would there be an easier way of doing what im attempting to do?

Comment: "Would there be an easier way of doing what im attempting to do?" - Yes.  Simply use an array of `Bar` objects.  Having a separate named variable for each bar is probably unnecessary.